# What are the wholesome qualities?

Tags: reference-request

Namo Buddhaya. At many places in the Suttas, Buddha calls for development of wholesome qualities. I guess Love , Joy , Compassion , Equanimity,Honesty,Conscience are wholesome qualities but that is the not the final list of wholesome qualities.

My question is : Is there a Sutta in which Buddha lists all the wholesome qualities one should develop in order to attain Nirvana?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 25 beautiful mental factors (sobhanaa cetasika) from the [Abhidhamma](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/mendis/wheel322.html#cetasika) (which is not sutta but is derived from the Buddha's teachings):

> The beautiful mental factors. There are twenty-five beautiful factors.
>   Nineteen are common to all beautiful thoughts, six are variable. The
>   latter are the three "abstinence factors," two "illimitables," and the
>   wisdom factor.
>
> The common beautiful factors (sobhanaa saadhaaranaa) are as follows:
>
> 1. Confidence (saddhaa), also called faith, which for a Buddhist means
>      trust in the Three Jewels — the Buddha, Dhamma, and Sangha, and in the
>      principles of the Buddha's teachings.
> 2. Mindfulness (sati): this is alertness, which makes us aware of what is
>      happening to us, from moment to moment, through the five physical
>      senses and the mind. Mindfulness is essential to insight meditation,
>      when it must be conjoined with a clear comprehension of the
>      suitability, purpose, and conformity with reality of any action. Then
>      it is called right mindfulness (sammaa sati). Usually the average
>      person acts without any form of mindfulness; his acts are prompted by
>      force of habit. Right mindfulness has two functions: one is to
>      increase the power of recollection and the other is to evaluate what
>      is wholesome and what is unwholesome. Right mindfulness is a spiritual
>      faculty that maintains a proper balance of the other faculties —
>      faith, energy, concentration and wisdom.
> 3. Shame of evil (hiri) and
> 4. fear of evil (ottappa) are the opposites
>      of the second and third unwholesome mental factors, already discussed.
> 5. Non-attachment (alobha) restrains attachment and fosters generosity.
> 6. Good-will (adosa) is synonymous with loving kindness (mettaa). It
>      keeps a person free from resentment and anger.
> 7. Equanimity (tatramajjhattaa, upekkhaa) is balance of mind, a quality
>      of neutrality free from attachment and repulsion.
>
> The other twelve common beautiful factors fall into six pairs, one member affecting the "body" of mental factors (kaaya), the other
>   affecting consciousness as a whole (citta). The six are as follows,
>   the terms themselves indicating their nature:
>
> 8. composure (passaddhi) of the mental factors
> 9. composure (passaddhi) of consciousness
> 10. buoyancy (lakhutaa) of the mental factors
> 11. buoyancy (lakhutaa) of consciousness
> 12. pliancy (mudutaa) of the mental factors
> 13. pliancy (mudutaa) of consciousness
> 14. efficiency (kammaññataa) of the mental factors
> 15. efficiency (kammaññataa) of consciousness
> 16. proficiency (paguññataa) of the mental factors
> 17. proficiency (paguññataa) of consciousness
> 18. rectitude (ujukataa) of the mental factors
> 19. rectitude (ujukataa) of consciousness
>
> The abstinence factors (virati) restrain a person from committing evil
>   acts. These are three in number:
>
> 20. Right speech (sammaa vacaa) is abstinence from lying, slandering,
>       abusive language, and idle talk.
> 21. Right action (sammaa kammantaa) is abstinence from killing, taking
>       what is not given, and wrong conduct with regard to sense pleasures.
> 22. Right livelihood (sammaa aajiiva) is abstinence from any livelihood
>       that brings harm to other living beings.
>
> The illimitable factors (appamaññaa) are compassion and sympathetic
>   joy; they are called illimitable because they are boundless and extend
>   to all living beings.
>
> 24. Compassion (karu.naa) has the nature of being moved by the suffering
>       of others. The sadness we might experience over the suffering or loss
>       of a loved one is not true compassion. Such sadness is sentimental, a
>       manifestation of grief. Real compassion arises when the mind, detached
>       from self-referential concerns, is stirred by the suffering of others,
>       feeling the suffering as its own.
> 25. Sympathetic joy (muditaa) has the nature of rejoicing in other's
>       happiness. Usually people rejoice at the success of someone who is
>       near and dear to them, but it is rare for them to rejoice when success
>       and prosperity are enjoyed by someone unknown, not to speak of an
>       adversary. Muditaa embraces all beings and cannot coexist with the
>       unwholesome mental factor of jealousy.
>
> Compassion and sympathetic joy, together with goodwill and equanimity,
>   form the Four Sublime Abodes (brahma vihaara). Goodwill and equanimity
>   were mentioned under the common beautiful factors.
>
> The wisdom factor (paññaa) enables one to see things as they truly
>   are, that is, in the light of impermanence, unsatisfactoriness and
>   selflessness.

Comment: Abhidhamma is the teaching of the Buddha

Comment: MN117 mentions "Thus, bhikkhus, there are twenty factors on the side of the wholesome, and twenty factors on the side of the unwholesome. " ....Are the twenty factors which are talked about in MN 117 a subset of AbhiDhamma which you have quoted above ?